# NEST Fluent DSL querying some URL field

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Got some question related to NEST. Below are some documents in my ES.

[image]

As you can see I already insert some entry in my ES. I tried do some query something like this:

```
        var response = elastic.Search<ESIntegrationLog>(s => s
                            .Index("20160806")
                            .Type("esintegrationlog")
                            .Query(q =>
                                q.Term(p => p.CalledBy, "lazada")
                            )
                            .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CalledOn))
                            .Take(300)
                        );
```

The outcome is just as I expected, I do found the entry. But when I tried to query by 'callPoint', I somehow cannot find any result. Below is the code:

```
        var response = elastic.Search<ESIntegrationLog>(s => s
                            .Index("20160806")
                            .Type("esintegrationlog")
                            .Query(q =>
                                q.Term(p => p.CallPoint, "/cloudconnect/api/xxxxxxx/v1")
                            )
                            .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CalledOn))
                            .Take(300)
                        );
```

I do already tried to encode the URL, but still does not find anything. Any ideas?

Update: I solve the case using 'match'.

```
.Query(q =>
    //q.Term(p => p.CallPoint, "abcdefg")
    q.MatchPhrasePrefix(c=> c.Field(d=> d.CallPoint).Query("/cloudconnect/api/xxxxxxx/v1"))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `callPoint` is an analyzed `string` field, which has been analyzed by the standard analyzer. You'll be able to see how `callPoint` is mapped by looking at the mappings in `20160806` index. Using [Sense](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/index.html)

```
GET 20160806
```

If the mapping for `callPoint` is `{ "type" : "string" }` then the input will be analyzed at index time. You can see how the standard analyzer will analyze the input using the `_analyze` API

```
POST _analyze
{
    "text" : "/cloudconnect/api/xxxxxxx/v1",
    "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

produces the following tokens

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "cloudconnect",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "api",
         "start_offset": 14,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "xxxxxxx",
         "start_offset": 18,
         "end_offset": 25,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "v1",
         "start_offset": 26,
         "end_offset": 28,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      }
   ]
}
```

[A `term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-term-query.html) does not analyze the query input so will be attempting to match the query input as is against what is in the inverted index, which for the `callPoint` field, has been analyzed at index time. [A `match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-match-query.html) does analyze the query input so you would get a match for the document as expected. Alternatively, you could map `callPoint` as a `not_analyzed` string field so that the input is not analyzed at index time and is indexed verbatim.

Comment: Thanks. Helps me a lot.

Comment: No worries, glad it helps :)